# Accessing the android fragments using adb commands

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity, command-line, adb

Similar to what I have seen for an `Activity` in Android being started using the following adb command :

```
startCommand = "adb shell am start -n " + appPackage + "/." + appActivity;
```

Is there a way to selectively start a fragment inside an activity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to add an `extra` named `:android:show_fragment` with the fragment name to your `am start` command:

```
am start -n com.android.settings/.Settings -e ":android:show_fragment" com.android.settings.LocalePicker
```